# How to load controls from assembly in ASP.NET MVC4 Razor view engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a DLL which contains header and footer for the webpages. In ASP.Net webforms i just registered the assembly and added tagprefix for that and i used the header and footer in that webform. But in MVC4 Razor view engine i am able to add assembly but i don't know how to use that in MVC4 Razor view engine. Anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a Visual Studio extension *Razor Generator*, which generates the C# code for razor views that can be compiled into the assembly. Also, it provides a view engine that loads the views from external references.